# Why is adding time in milliseconds show incorrect results?

Tags: java, datetime

I can't figure out what is going on with the below code in my debug view:

```
public void addTime(int day, long offsetMillis) {

    long currentTime = mCalendar.getTimeInMillis();
    long newTime = currentTime + offsetMillis;

    Date offsetDate = new Date(offsetMillis);
    Date currentDate = new Date(currentTime);
    Date newDate = new Date(newTime);
    // ...
}
```

[image]

I have time in milliseconds that I need to add to the current time. Looking at the debug state I can see that offsetDate translates to 23:46 which is the correct amount of time I want to add.

currentDate is the current time, which is the start of a given day 00:00.

newDate is the current time plus the offset, which translates to 13:46.

That is incorrect, It looks like the GMT is the difference here but as you can see, the GMT are all +10 in the debug view. So I cannot for the life of me figure out what Java is doing... Please help me solve this problem? Given a time in milliseconds, how do I add it to a given date?

Comment: You should ideally be using `java.time` classes rather than `Date`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the calculations are correct. The amount of milliseconds you specified is actually equal to 13 hours and 46 minutes. offsetDate only shows you 23:46, because the timezone is set to GMT+10.

Unix Timestamps work by counting the amount of milliseconds elapsed since 1 January 1970 00:00 UTC. This date is equivalent to 1 January 1970 10:00 UTC+10. Therefore, the time displayed for your offsetDate is itself offset by 10 hours.

Answer (score 1):

[Answer by 3141](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44218040/642706) is correct and should be accepted.

## tl;dr

```
Instant.now().plusMillis( 84_456_000L ) // In UTC.
```

## java.time

This work would be easier and clearer with the java.time classes that supplant the troublesome old date-time classes.

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant now = Instant.now() ;
Instant later = now.plusMillis( 84_456_000L ) ;
```

Or represent your span of time as an object.

```
Duration d = Duration.ofMillis( 84_456_000L ) ;
```

Or…

```
Duration d = Duration.ofHours( 23 ).plus( Duration.ofMinutes( 46 ) ) ;
```

Apply the duration.

```
Instant later = now.plus( d ) ;
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to specify your timezone. For example:

```
Date curr_date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis("YOUR_TIMEZONE_HERE"));
```